# Loop plot creation and save for thousands of variables

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

i have a script to produce nice plots for my data, but i need to make thousands of these plots. So is there a way to loop a script and run it through all variables in the data sheet.

Here is my script, its not really reproducible but its just ggplot commands, i guess i need to understand how to make it go in a loop. Basically everything that has yield should be changed to another variable from data frame

```
Yield <- data_summary(data2, varname="Yield", 
                      groupnames=c("Variety", "year", "group"))
Yield_to_year <-ggplot(Yield, aes(x=year, y=Yield, color=group)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=group), size=2.5)+
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, formula = y ~ poly(x, 2), size=1, fill="grey85")+ 
  #For confidence interval, se=TRUE 
  #Linear regression: formula = y ~ x
  #Polynomial: formula = y ~ poly(x, 2)
  stat_regline_equation(formula = y ~ poly(x, 2), show.legend = FALSE, size=3, label.x = 1970,)+
  #Linear regression: formula = y ~ x
  #Polynomial: formula = y ~ poly(x, 2)
  stat_cor(method = "pearson", r.accuracy=0.01, p.accuracy=0.001, show.legend = FALSE, , size=3, label.x = 1985,)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Yield-sd, ymax = Yield+sd), colour="grey", width=1)+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill="white", colour=NA, size=0, linetype="solid"), 
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=1.2),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "right",
        text = element_text(size=16),
        plot.title=element_text(size=16, face="bold"),
        plot.subtitle=element_text(size=12, face="italic"))+
  ylab("Kg/Ha")+
  xlab("Year")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1940,2020,10), limits=c(1933, 2020))+
  scale_colour_manual(legend_title, labels = c("Bread wheat irrigated", "Bread wheat rainfed", "Durum wheat irrigated", "Durum wheat rainfed"), values=c("navy", "royalblue1", "violetred4", "darkorange1"))+
  geom_text_repel(aes(label=""), show.legend = FALSE) #Write Variety in label to see what is each point
Yield_to_year
tiff(file="Yield_to_year.tiff", width=25, height=15, units="cm", res=300)
Yield_to_year
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Thanks for updating your question with data; I'm not sure if I've interpreted your desired outcome correctly, but hopefully this is what you're after:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
library(ggrepel)

df <- read.csv("~/Desktop/Data.csv") %>%
  select(where(~!all(is.na(.x))))
  
Yield <- df %>%
  group_by(year, Var, group) %>%
  summarise(Yield, mean = mean(Yield), sd = sd(Yield))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'year', 'Var', 'group'. You can override
#> using the `.groups` argument.


yield_function <- function(var) {
  var <- ensym(var)
  df %>%
    group_by(year, Var, group) %>%
    mutate(mean_var := mean(!!var, na.rm = TRUE),
           sd_var := sd(!!var, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = !!var, color = group)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = group), size = 2.5) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE,
              formula = y ~ poly(x, 2), size = 1, fill = "grey85") +
  #For confidence interval, se=TRUE
  #Linear regression: formula = y ~ x
  #Polynomial: formula = y ~ poly(x, 2)
  stat_regline_equation(formula = y ~ poly(x, 2), show.legend = FALSE,
                        size=3, label.x = 1970) +
  #Linear regression: formula = y ~ x
  #Polynomial: formula = y ~ poly(x, 2)
  stat_cor(method = "pearson", r.accuracy = 0.01,
           p.accuracy = 0.001, show.legend = FALSE,
           size = 3, label.x = 1985) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean_var - sd_var,
                    ymax = mean_var - sd_var),
                colour = "grey", width = 1) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = NA,
                                        size = 0, linetype = "solid"),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, size = 1.2),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        text = element_text(size=16),
        plot.title=element_text(size=16, face="bold"),
        plot.subtitle=element_text(size=12, face="italic"))+
  ylab(as.name(var))+
  xlab("Year")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1940,2020,10), limits=c(1933, 2020))+
  scale_colour_manual(labels = c("Bread wheat irrigated", "Bread wheat rainfed", "Durum wheat irrigated", "Durum wheat rainfed"),
                      values=c("navy", "royalblue1", "violetred4", "darkorange1"))+
  geom_text_repel(aes(label=""), show.legend = FALSE)
  ggsave(filename = paste0("yield_according_to_", var, ".png"),
         width = 25, height = 15, units = "cm")
}

yield_function(X77.NDVI)
```

[image: example_1.png]

```r
variables_to_plot <- names(df[-c(1:6)])
variables_to_plot
#>  [1] "X77.NDVI"   "X77.GNDVI"  "X77.AREA"   "X90.AREA"   "X97.AREA"  
#>  [6] "X109.NDVI"  "X109.GNDVI" "X109.AREA"  "X125.NDVI"  "X125.GNDVI"
#> [11] "X125.AREA"  "X136.NDVI"  "X136.GNDVI" "X136.AREA"

lapply(variables_to_plot, yield_function)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "yield_according_to_X77.NDVI.png"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "yield_according_to_X77.GNDVI.png"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "yield_according_to_X77.AREA.png"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "yield_according_to_X90.AREA.png"
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] "yield_according_to_X97.AREA.png"
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] "yield_according_to_X109.NDVI.png"
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] "yield_according_to_X109.GNDVI.png"
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1] "yield_according_to_X109.AREA.png"
#> 
#> [[9]]
#> [1] "yield_according_to_X125.NDVI.png"
#> 
#> [[10]]
#> [1] "yield_according_to_X125.GNDVI.png"
#> 
#> [[11]]
#> [1] "yield_according_to_X125.AREA.png"
#> 
#> [[12]]
#> [1] "yield_according_to_X136.NDVI.png"
#> 
#> [[13]]
#> [1] "yield_according_to_X136.GNDVI.png"
#> 
#> [[14]]
#> [1] "yield_according_to_X136.AREA.png"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

(Some of the generated plots)

[image: image_1.png]

[image: image_2.png]

[image: image_3.png]

### Original answer

One potential solution is to create a function that generates your desired output, then apply the function to each of your 'variables of interest, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- mtcars

list_of_variables_to_plot <- names(df)[3:7]
list_of_variables_to_plot
#> [1] "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec"

plotting_function <- function(var) {
  var <- ensym(var)
  p <- df %>%
    mutate(Make = factor(am, labels = c("European",
                                        "American")),
           cyl = factor(cyl)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = !!var, group = cyl)) +
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
    geom_point(aes(fill = Make), shape = 21,
               position = position_jitter(width = 0.2,
                                          height = 0)) +
    ggtitle(paste0("Correlation between ", var,
                   " and number of cylinders"))
  print(p)
}

lapply(list_of_variables_to_plot, plotting_function)
```

```
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[3]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[4]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[5]]
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Instead of printing the plots you can save them to file from within the function. If you are able to provide some example data and explain/show your expected outcome it would be easier to illustrate this approach.

Comment: Yes, I would prefer to save the files right away.
Here is the data Im using - https://drive.google.com/file/d/15lmQ_hQnguIByg7tXykt-liXyosBkMGK/view?usp=sharing

And the output should be something like this
https://drive.google.com/file/d/121fCYSZ9fUvgWkTUpyENnW6ML-ogpf5w/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks @ArtūrsKatamadze - I've updated my answer. Hopefully that's your intended goal, but if not, please edit your question with the changes you want made.

Comment: Thanks! the script works perfectly, but something went wrong with error bars, not sure what, but it is showing a random tick on the plot, its also visible on the plots you generated.

Comment: Hmmm - I'm not sure - I deleted your data @ArtūrsKatamadze so I can't test it, but perhaps try adding `group = 1` or `group = year` inside the ggplot `aes()`, e.g. `ggplot(aes(x = year, y = !!var, color = group, group = year))`? If that doesn't work, best thing to do is to ask a new question with a sample of the data (i.e. `dput(head(Yield))` or a smaller 'example' dataset that illustrates the problem).